# Ordering Color by Hex Value

Tags: c#, colors, gradient, rgb, color-theory

I'm not sure how to classify this question, nor explain it effectively, but I'll do my best.

I have a series of random Hex code values gathered from my app.

I want to present these colors in a gradient, that will (in theory) show the prominence of one group of colors.

As in, if in my random array of colors there are more blue shades, then putting it into this gradient will reflect that.

But first, I need to "order" the colors in the gradient to be next to like colors.

I'm using C# -- but moreso just after the theory on how to map/order/group Hex color values together.

Comment: In what format do you have those values? Is it a .net Drawing.Color or is it just text?

Comment: You could convert them to HSV and order by hue.

Comment: no real order is possible as color space is 3d and linear gradients are 1d. So you need to project 3d -> 1d. conversion to Color or the HSV is a good first step but then you will have to decide.. See [here for a discussion of color distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621?s=1|1.0462#27375621)

Comment: @llouk I have the HEX values as strings

Comment: @DavidConrad This sounds interesting, would you have any links? Thanks :)

Comment: @TaW Thanks for the link very useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I used the Hue method as commented, which results in the below -- which is works great, as you can see shows that there were more Blue colors in my List of colors (which is set dynamically) so thanks again.

BUT there is still a bug in it -- it's repeating instead of taking up the entire height for some reason :( (should only be 1 Linear from blues to reds)

(I'll open another question for this).

[image: LinearGradientBrush]

My code was as follows (ColorFromString was a method I wrote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966951/c-sharp-colortranslator-fromhtml-throws-exception-for-grey-is-not-a-valid-v/36967249#36967249)):

```
private Color[] OrderColorByHue(List<string> colors)
{
  foreach(string c in colors)
  {
    Color color = ColorFromString(c); // This was defined in another question of mine :)
    float hue = color.GetHue();

    hueColors.Add(new KeyValuePair<Color, float>(color, hue));
  }

  hueColors.Sort((color1, color2) => color2.Value.CompareTo(color1.Value));
  Color[] value = hueColors.Select(color => color.Key).ToArray();

  return value;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: This could more succinctly be written as:
return colors.Select(ColorFromString).OrderBy(c => c.GetHue()).ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

```
    // GET: Admin/Colors
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var colors = db.Colors.OrderBy(a => a.HexCode);
        return View(colors);
    }
```

I used it in my MVC.Net project. 
I think you may modify it for yourself.

HexCodes must begin with '#' (important for ordering)